# Sending and receiving more lines via a serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port

*(Editor's note. Possibly related: [SerialPort Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))*

I'm trying to send commands to an RFID-Reader and receive the "answers."

For example, `port.Write("S")` and `port.ReadLine()` will receive the UID if the reader can read a tag.

I'm using [SerialDataReceivedEventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialdatareceivedeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);

private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    port.ReadLine();  
}
```

And this is where I'm sending the commands:

```
public void sendData()
{
    port.Write("S");
    port.Write("r01");
    port.Write("r02");
}
```

Now the problem is that I receive only the first answer to "S" and it won't send all 3 lines. The problem is that I don't know how to send all 3 commands to the reader.

If I ignore `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler` I find that I can use this code:

```
public void sendandreceive()
{
    port.Write("S");
    port.ReadLine();
    port.Write("r01");
    port.ReadLine();
}
```

That code will send and receive both commands and answers. But I read that it is a good idea to use the `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler`.

Comment: `port.WriteLine("S");` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

When the DataReceived event fires, it will not fire again unless more data arrives. What is happening is that the serial port's buffer contains all three responses and you're only reading one.

Using DataRecived can be complicated if you have a message structure that has to be parsed (which you do, each message ends in a EOL terminator). There are a lot of ways to solve this problem.

You could read all available bytes into a buffer and pull out complete messages, then fire another event, one per message. If there is a partial message in the buffer, leave it until the next DataReceived event.

You could perform the entire operation (sendandreceive in your example above) as an asynchronous operation which signals when it's done. This is the simplest method. Keep in mind that SerialPort.ReadLine can timeout and throw a TimeoutException if it doesn't get a complete "line" in time. It's not the most robust solution because of this. You have to consider what to do if the operation timed out (there may be an incomplete message in the buffer).

Which method you use will depend on the nature of the application. Is the protocol always "send a command, get a response"? Or do some commands result in continuous responses?

Doing serial communications correctly (robustly) is hard. I would start with the easiest solution and test it carefully.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. (press enter will save this post..good to know :D ) another way i tried was that i put the port.Write(comman) and the .ReadLine into the  port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
and made a count var and a case. For example: case 0: .write("S") count++ break; case 1: .write("r01") count++ break; and so on and a string[] which saves the information. string[count] = .ReadLine(); Hope you know what i mean as i don't know how to format this post right. I will also try the asynchron method. I will post as soon as I tried it out.

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine if I use the `sendandreceive` method so I will use this and won't use `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler`.

I was a little bit confused because in every serial port example `SerialDataReceivedEventHandler` is used.

Still, I need to test it before I can say that it works without any problems. That said, I'm open to other suggestions.